# My Long-standing Website Looks like S#*@ on iOS8 Safari Now

Tags: ios8, mobile-safari

My website has been around for many years.  It looked fine on Safari on iOS7.  Got my new iPhone 6 yesterday, checked out my website, and it has all kinds of errors.  Looks terrible.  I checked it with Chrome on iOS8, looks fine.  Checked it out on desktops and it looks fine.

Is there a bug in iOS8 or did they make some unannounced change that web devs need to know about?

Here's my site:
http://optimalauctions.com

Comment: I've been getting really erratic behaviour on a site we did. I haven't found a fix yet but looked into elements using position: fixed might be causing an issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108777/ios8-safari-website-links-do-not-work-after-scrolling

Comment: Hi I checked your website, and it looks fine, did 8.0.2 fix it or did you find a solution yourself?

Comment: No, it's still incorrect.  I'm on the 6+, but it looks OK on the 6.  I'm chalking it up to bad caching maybe, and hoping it'll go away.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the app's cache (gzipped CSS and JS files) and it started working.  Not sure what caused this.